# PHP saving the output of a function in a variable?

Tags: php, html

I am trying accomplish this:

```
$productlist= $tpl->draw( 'products' );
```

Later I want to echo it on some other file:

while the $tpl->draw( 'products' ) displaying some output for example

```
<div id="productlist>
include("products");
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: $tryt ='<div id="productlist">
include("products");
</div>
';

echo $tryt; This is going to work i guess, use sessions to store or save it in db

Answer (score 0):

you can expose your data to another script by using a session variable, or storing and retrieving from a database or flatfile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$productlist= $tpl->draw( 'products' );
```

//class file

```
class drawing{

  function draw($type) {

  $str='';

   if($type=='')
    $type='default'

    $ids=$type.'list';

    $str="<div id='$ids'> include('$type') </div>";
    return $str;
 }
}
```